# How can I see errors which I get in my Controller in UserManager CreateAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create user with `UserManager` and `CreateAsync` method, but it doesn't work. Im postman I always get `200 OK`

My Post method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
        {
            User user = new User { Email = "asfa@gmail.com", UserName = "asfa@gmail.com" };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "SS22!faasd");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // install cookie
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    //how can i see my errors here
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Also I dont have any cshtml files, so I cant output them on page.
Or you can just explain, why my `CreateAsync` method doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I can see them using `Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: @AmirPopovich this doesn't work for me

Comment: I don't think that password meets the complexity requirements... if that's actually what you're using

Comment: @crgolden It contains numbers, letters in up and down register, symbols, why is it bad?

Comment: You're right - that would be complex enough.

Comment: @crgolden So, do you know, how can I see my errors?

Comment: Are you able to debug this code? Then just press SHIFT+F9 over the result.Errors. By the way, your code always end with _return Ok()_ even in case of error. You should _return BadRequest()_ or something inside the else error block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return the result from the server every time:

```cs
return Ok(result);
```

It will be serialized so you can see it.

Comment: Where I can see it?